# Terraform version is giving incorrect version in windows

Tags: terraform, version

I noticed when I run **terraform version** in command prompt is not giving the correct terraform version, I just downloaded and kept in c:/terraform folder.

Comment: After spending some time on goggle I realized, I have already installed terraform using chocolatey and it was installed in the path C:\ProgramData\chcolatey.

Answer (score 0):

If you notice terraform version command in command prompt is not giving the correct terraform version, you just downloaded and kept in c:/terraform path then check these two things.

1. Check whether you Updated system path variable with c:/terraform
2. Check where terraform was installed using (get-command terraform.exe).Path in PowerShell.
3. Check whether you already installed terraform using chocolatey.